# saveAll HABTM not saving all

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a HABTM relationship in both my models.

**Person.php**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Tag' =>
        array(
  'className' => 'Api.Tag'
));
```

**Tag.php**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Person' =>
        array(
        'className' => 'Api.Person',

    ));
```

**PeopleController.php**

```
public function edit(){
    $results = $this->Person->saveAll($this->request->data);
}
```

_

```
(
[id] => 554d92e1-7920-409a-b348-080e2773a233
[firstname] => George
[lastname] => Jones
[Company] => Array
    (
        [id] => 554995a3-f880-4a02-b971-9ac82773a233
        [title] => xxxx
    )

[Tag] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array //this is an existing tag
            (
                [id] => 530e487c-44bc-4ffe-ae2b-152f4056922c
                [title] => monkey
                [PeopleTag] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 554e741d-a98c-48d0-8a52-080c2773a233
                        [tag_id] => 530e487c-44bc-4ffe-ae2b-152f4056922c
                        [person_id] => 554d92e1-7920-409a-b348-080e2773a233
                        [created] => -62169987600
                        [modified] => 1431207117
                    )
            )

        [1] => Array //this is a new tag that's not being added
            (
                [title] => rocketship
            )

        [2] => Array //this is a new tag that's not being added
            (
                [title] => houses
            )

    )

)
```

When I manually set tags in the database I'm able to read them back out into my app correctly and when I delete existing tags, they get removed from the database.  The problem is though that nothing gets added when I try to use cakephp to add them.

My data array looks a little funky because I'm actually using this plugin to transform things. 
http://friendsofcake.com/crud/docs/listeners/api-transformation.html

my CakePHP app is getting this data below, but it's not adding my new tags nor is it adding my associations in the people_tags join table.  Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If it comes to insert data then you have to do it sperately, only deletion happens automatically if in model dependency is true. For rest you have to yourself.

Comment: That seems strange that it would delete "automagically" but not save. Can you explain why?  Just curious.

Comment: Please read cakephp documentation because its not possible to give description you right here.

Comment: An option is available also in the form of Model::saveAssociated(array $data = null, array $options = array()). Please read here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html and do accordingaly. cheers

Comment: I gave you a link to check. it's not helping you?

Comment: No, I already tried that.

Comment: Sorry for my odd words if it seems to you odd.

Comment: I found another link.  The only problem with it though is my beforeSave isn't getting called and I need to inject extra data on each save:

http://patisserie.keensoftware.com/en/pages/how-to-save-habtm-data-in-cakephp

Comment: @anant `saveAll()` *does* save associated data (as long as the data is keyed in properly)